# Jest enzyme mobx, testing that stores are passed to a provider

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs, mobx, mobx-react

This is the entry point of my app (where I initialize and pass the mobx store):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";

import App from "./App";

import UiStore from "./stores/UiStore";
const uiStore = new UiStore();

ReactDOM.render(<App stores={{ uiStore }} />, document.getElementById("root"));

registerServiceWorker();
```

This is the App component I am passing the store to component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { observer, Provider } from "mobx-react";

import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

import Main from "./components/Main";
import Header from "./components/Header";
@observer
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider {...this.props.stores}>
        <Router>
          <div className="app-container">
            <Header />
            <Main />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now I want to test that it is properly passing the mobx stores to the provider.

This is my test:

```
import React from "react";

import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { mount } from "enzyme";

import App from "./App";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Main from "./components/Main";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("App.js", () => {
  it("passes stores into the provider", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    expect(wrapper.find("Provider").props()).toBe("");
  });
});
```

But the test fails with the following result:

```
Expected value to be (using ===):
      ""
    Received:
      {"children": <BrowserRouter><div className="app-container"><Header /><Main /></div></BrowserRouter>}
```

From what I see here, the only prop that my test finds is children, but not the store. How can I test for the destructured props?

Comment: You are not giving your `App` component a store in the test, like you are in the code. Have you tried `const wrapper = mount(<App stores={{ uiStore }}/>);`?

Comment: @Tholle you are correct, passing the props to the App component solved my problem. All makes sense now :). Write it up as an anwser and I will accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving your `App` component a store in the test, like you are in the code. It should work if you do the following:

```
const wrapper = mount(<App stores={{ uiStore }}/>);
```